# Removing headertoolbar of GridPanel in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel

I have a `GridPanel` in `Extjs` and i just want to remove or hide its header toolbar. (The toolbar where the title and the searchbox is in). I just want the `Gridpanels` first element to be the column headers. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find a suitable config option, calling `gridPanel.getTopToolbar().hide()` afterwards should do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

hideHeaders property of Ext.grid.GridPanel does the trick.

```
var grid = new.Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    hideHeaders: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
}
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the [header](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) config option to false? See below example:

```
 var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        cm: cm,
        header: false,
        renderTo: 'mygrid',
        width: 600,
        height: 300
    });
```